# Unable to access the Index value inside template Ref

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm unable to access the index inside the templateRef, It throws undefined in console.

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let notification of notifications; let i = index">
    <ng-template 
      *ngTemplateOutlet="notificatioPageContent; context: { notification: notification, index: i  }">
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #notificatioPageContent let-notification=notification let-index=i>
```

I'm able to access the notification value, but not the index value. Please help

****Update**

```
<ng-template #notificationPageContent let-notification=notification let-index=i>
          <notification
          (notificationClosed)="notificationCloseHandler($event, i)"
          >
```

When the button is clicked, I'm calling the `notificationClosed` function. But here still the `i` is undefined. Please tell me what i'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Try this : We are taking index value incorrectly check line #1 for correct syntax, you will be getting 'i' as index now that we are passing o TemplateOutlet as index that you will get as index at ng-template.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let notification of notifications;index as i">
    <ng-template 
      *ngTemplateOutlet="notificatioPageContent; context: { notification: notification, index: i  }">
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #notificatioPageContent let-notification=notification let-index=i>
```

Hope it helps... Happy coding :)

Comment: still i'm not able to access the value of index